# Audio player to play the remote audio file in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I need to play the audio file (.wav) in iPhone from a website. I am using the MPMoviePlayerViewController to play the audio player. Some times the application is getting a crash.

My Code:

NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:appDelegate.selectedQuestion.GraphicsUrl];

```
        videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
        [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0];
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [videoPlayer moviePlayer];

        [moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];
        [videoPlayer.view setFrame: videoView.bounds];
        [moviePlayer.view setFrame:videoPlayer.view.bounds];
        [moviePlayer.backgroundView setFrame:videoPlayer.view.bounds];  
        [videoView addSubview:videoPlayer.view];

        [moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO];
        [moviePlayer setCurrentPlaybackTime:(NSTimeInterval)1];
        [moviePlayer setInitialPlaybackTime:(NSTimeInterval)1];
        [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
        [moviePlayer setCurrentPlaybackTime:(NSTimeInterval)-1];
```

Exception:

```
 mediaserverd (sandbox)
Dec 29 23:48:43 unknown mediaserverd[3132] <Error>: 23:48:43.312834 com.apple.AVConference: /SourceCache/GameKitServices/GameKitServices-344.3/AVConference.subproj/Sources/AVConferenceServer.m:1867: AVConferenceServerStart
Dec 29 23:48:43 unknown SMILE[2823] <Warning>: _serverConnectionDiedNotification. Info -- notification=Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 "Cannot Complete Action" UserInfo=0x7f7c660 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Action}, AVPlayer = <MPQueuePlayer: 0xac97410>, currentTime = 8.78
Dec 29 23:48:43 unknown SMILE[2823] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'
```

Comment: I am not sure why you are using two instances(videoPlayer, moviePlayer)? If you see the crash it is showing :  'An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'. Also, I am not aware of method -[MPMoviePlayerController moviePlayer]. For remove audio playing there are several question you can refer to them.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same crash before, and I fixed it by removing all the MPMoviePlayerController notifications and also release the MPMoviePlayerController itself (be noted, both should be done, otherwise the crash will still occur!) once the playback state went to MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped. I still don't know the exact reason, only thing I know is that if the player goes into MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped state continuously, it will crash, so I simply prevent it from stop twice.

Hope this will help.